# Trying to understand what xwd:- does in convert xwd:-

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to reverse engineer the following:

```
xwd -silent | convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:-
```

I know that that ultimately this sequence will determine the rgb values for a screen cordinate.

I know that `xwd` takes a screen dump and this is piped to the convert command.

I have never seen anything like `xwd:-` and `txt:-` before.  What do the `xwd:-` and `txt:-` do?  Can you give a link to more information on this bash syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> *What do the xwd:- and txt:- do? Can you give a link to more
>   information on this bash syntax?*

Just to clarify, that is *not* bash syntax.  Those are part of convert's syntax.

`xwd:-` tells `convert` to get its input from stdin, where `-` means stdin, and expect the input to be in `xwd` format.

`txt:-` tells `convert` to send its output to stdout, where `-` means stdout, and to send the output in `txt` format.

#### More detail

- `xwd -silent`

  This captures an X window as an image and sends that output to stdout in XWD format.  By default, `xwd` rings bells when the window capture starts and ends.  `-silent` tells it to be quiet.
- `convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:-`

  This uses the ImageMagick's `convert` utility.  `xwd:-` tells it to accept an XWD format image on stdin.  `-depth 8` tells it to convert the image to depth 8.  `-crop "1x1+$X+$Y"` tells it to crop the image to a single pixel at location `X` and `Y`.  `txt:-` tells it to send information about that pixel in text form to stdout.

To understand `txt` output, let's look at an example.  Here is the output from cropping an image to a 2 pixel by 2 pixel size:

```
$ xwd -silent | convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "2x2+200+200" txt:-
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2,2,255,srgb
0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
1,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,1: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
1,1: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

As you can see, each pixel is identified by its location in the cropped image, its RGB color in two formats, and, when available,  the common name of color.

#### More examples

A jpeg file can be converted to png using a similar syntax:

```
cat out.jpg | convert jpg:- png:- >out.png
```

Of course, in thus simple example, the pipeline is superfluous.  The above can be simplified to:

```
convert jpg:out.jpg png:out.png
```

Further, if the file format is not specified, `convert` will guess it from the file extensions.  So, for files with recognizable file extensions, the following also works:

```
convert out.jpg out.png
```

#### Documentation

Running `convert` without arguments produces a help message.  At the end of the help message is an explanation of the meaning of `xwd:-` and `txt:-`:

> By default, the image format of `file' is determined by its magic
>   number.  To specify a particular image format, precede the filename
>   with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the
>   image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).  Specify 'file' as
>   '-' for standard input or output.